# Proving the Existence of a Number without Constructing

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility, constructive-mathematics

> Prove that for all $k \in \mathbb{N}$ then there exists $n$ such that
> $$
> 7^k \mid 2^n + 5^n + 3 
> $$

My idea is to construct $n$ such that the equation above is valid. However, the construction that I got is $$n = 3 \cdot 7^{k - 1} + 1$$
which is very weird and almost impossible to find without the help of a computer.

Is there a way to prove the existence of $n$ without constructing one?

Comment: This seems provable using induction did you try that?

Comment: $n-1=\phi(7^k)/2$, where $\phi$ is [Euler's totient function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function)

Comment: Are you familiar with lifting the exponent lemma?

Comment: @wjmccann I am curious how to use induction, can you please answer or give a hint (of course with/without construction)?

Comment: you could prove by induction that $7^k\mid 2^{3\cdot7^{k-1}}-1$ and $7^k\mid5^{3\cdot7^{k-1}}+1$, and from those it follows that $7^k\mid2^{3\cdot7^{k-1}+1}-2+5^{3\cdot7^{k-1}+1}+5=2^n+5^n+3$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The construction $n=3\cdot7^{k-1}+1$ is not so weird or impossible to find.

By [Euler's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function#Euler%27s_theorem), $a^{\phi(7^k)}\equiv1\bmod7^k$ if $7\nmid a$, where $\phi$ is Euler's totient function,

and $a^{\phi(7^k)/2}\equiv\pm1\bmod7^k$, and $\phi(7^k)=6\cdot7^{k-1}$.

$2^{\phi(7^1)/2}=8\equiv1\bmod7$, and $5^{\phi(7^1)/2}=125\equiv-1\bmod7$,

so $2^{\phi(7^k)/2}\equiv1\bmod7^k$, and $5^{\phi(7^k)/2}\equiv-1\bmod7^k$.

Therefore, $2^n+5^n+3\equiv 2-5+3=0\bmod7^k$.

Answer (score 2):

Notice that $ 2 - 5 + 3 = 0 $.
So the motivation is to find a $7^k \mid 2^n - 2, 7^k \mid 5^n + 5 $, or that $ 7^k \mid 2^{n-1} - 1, 7^k \mid 5^{n-1} + 1 $.

If you're familiar with the [Lifting the Exponent lemma](https://brilliant.org/wiki/lifting-the-exponent/), this is pretty standard.

- Show that $2^3 \equiv 1 \pmod{7}$ and $ 5^3 \equiv -1 \pmod {7}$.
- LTE thus gives us  $v_7(2^{3m} - 1^{3m}) = v_7(2^3 - 1) + v_7(3m)$ and $v_7 (5^{3m} - (-1)^{3m} ) = v_7(5^3 - (-1)) + v_7 (3m)$.
- In particular, for $m = 7^{k-1}$, $ 7^k \mid 2^{3m} - 1$, $7^k \mid 5^{3m} + 1$, which is what we need.
- Thus, $ n = 3\times 7^{k-1} + 1$ works.

Note

- It follows that any $n =  A \times 3\times 7^{k-1} + 1$ will work.